# Classe .text-justify do Bootstrap 3 não alinha sem nenhum herança anterior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Inseri uma classe em uma div para justificar o texto interno mas não respeita, e não há heranças de classes ou elementos de nível superior.

```
<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
    <div class='text-justify'>
        Lorem ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. lorem ipsum has been the
industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. it has survived not only five centuries... 
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ficando assim:**

[image: Texto Lorem Ipsum]

**E a saída do inspetor de elementos do Firefox está assim:**

```
element {
}
.text-justify {
    text-align: justify;
}
html, body, div, applet, object, iframe p, blockquote, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    font-variant-numeric: lining-nums;
    font-feature-settings: 'lnum';
    -moz-font-feature-settings: 'lnum=1';
}
```

Comment: Aqui funcionou...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seu erro pode ser aqui `<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6">` Repare que vc abre com aspas simples `'` e fecha com aspas duplas `"`

Veja que abaixo funciona corretamente.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
        <div class='text-justify'>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse atque deserunt accusantium quia recusandae, officia assumenda totam mollitia minima provident voluptatum odit neque fuga aperiam sint iste cupiditate dignissimos, tempora consequuntur suscipit iure ad delectus eius repellat. Incidunt eveniet ducimus magni sunt quasi molestiae, consequatur similique distinctio minima, vitae error.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Cara, hoje estou com a cabeça voada, segunda vez que fico um tempão repassando código por erro de digitação, obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Comment: @EliseuB. :D toma um café !

Comment: rsrsrs podicreh